# Videos have a horizontal cut when played on VLC on 16.04 or 18.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, 18.04, video, vlc

I have an X230 Tablet, with two separate partitions, one of them has Ubuntu-MATE 14.04, and the other has Ubuntu-MATE 16.04.

When playing any video file on 14.04, everything looks perfect.

But when reproducing them (the same ones) in 16.04, they look like a horizontal cut in the image that bothers a lot.

In Ubuntu-MATE 18.04 the same thing happens.

The 14.04 has these packages installed:

```
$ dpkg -l * vlc * | grep ii
ii libvlc5 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.4 amd64 multimedia player and streamer library
ii libvlccore7 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.4 amd64 base library for VLC and its modules
ii vlc 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.4 amd64 multimedia player and streamer
ii vlc-data 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.4 all Common data for VLC
ii vlc-nox 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.4 amd64 multimedia player and streamer (without X support)
ii vlc-plugin-pulse 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.4 amd64 PulseAudio plugin for VLC
```

The 16.04 has installed these others:

```
$ dpkg -l * vlc * | grep ii
ii libvlc5 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4 amd64 multimedia player and streamer library
ii libvlccore8 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4 amd64 base library for VLC and its modules
ii vlc 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4 amd64 multimedia player and streamer
ii vlc-data 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4 all Common data for VLC
ii vlc-nox 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4 amd64 multimedia player and streamer (without X support)
ii vlc-plugin-notify 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4 amd64 LibNotify plugin for VLC
ii vlc-plugin-samba 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4 amd64 Samba plugin for VLC
```

So, what can be the cause and/or how can it be solved?

---

I attach the image.

But it is very difficult to make a screenshot and to see the problem sufficiently well.

Could it be the problem of the video drivers that takes 16.04 and 18.04?
[image]

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like screen tearing, which is typically caused by a mismatch between the framerate of the software you are using and the refresh rate of the monitor.

You should be able to fix this by enabling vertical sync in your video adapter settings.